# Does m3u8 playlist support seekto function if ENDLIST key not found

Tags: android, video-streaming, m3u8, android-videoview

is it possible to use seekTo function into a  m3u8 stream if this playlist does not have #EXT-X-ENDLIST key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i have tested on many different android builds and versions NO!

Comment: as it is mentioned. Android doesnt support dvr. Thanks Guro